# Can't execute py file in Jupyterlab terminal

Tags: python, jupyter

[Jupyterlab Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT7K7.png)

From the image above it can be seen that test1.py is found in the dir.
when i run  `PS C:\Users\sheddyranking> python test.py`

I get the erro belew

`C:\Users\sheddyranking\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\sheddyranking\\test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Run `python test1.py` not `python test.py`

Comment: i did same error

Comment: i even created another file  same error